# Java/Angularjs - convert variable names to normal English conventions

Tags: java, angularjs

My goal here is to retrieve the attribute names from a class, which I have already done using `JAVA Reflections`. But I want to be able to transform the variable naming convention, say `firstName` to `First Name`.

My current idea is to use `.split()` to transform `position: 0` (usually a lower-case) to `Uppercase`, then loop until I find subsequent UpperCases, and push a blank space in between. Are there any better way to do this?

EDIT: This is my current method if any of you are interested:

```
public List<String> getProfileConstraintTemplateEnglish() {
    //what I want to return
    List<String> transformedList = new ArrayList<>();
    //The reflection that I'm getting
    List<ResultProfileConstraintTemplate> tmp = constraintService.getProfileCTml();

    //loop each obj in reflection list
    for (ResultProfileConstraintTemplate r : tmp) {

        //get the letters first from the title in obj
        String[] field = r.getTitle().split("");

        //this is the transformed string in each tmp.
        String transformed = "";
        //converting the array to a list for simpler addition.
        List<String> fieldString = Arrays.asList(field);

        //adding a counter to know which is the "first" position.
        int counter = 0;
        for (String s : fieldString) {
            //first letter
            if (counter == 0) {
                transformed += s.toUpperCase();
            }
            //everything else
            if (counter != 0 && s.equals(s.toUpperCase())) {
                transformed+= " ";
                transformed+=s;
            }
            else if(counter != 0 && s.equals(s.toLowerCase())){
                transformed+=s;
            }
            //increment counter
            counter++;
        }
        //add the transformed word to list.
        transformedList.add(transformed);
    }
    return transformedList;
}
```

Result:

[image: Current Result]

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is the only way. If you post your code, maybe we can shed more light on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isUpperCase() method and if it returns true replace it with a space and the letter and always convert first letter i.e indexOf(0) to toUpperCase().